# sp_send_dbmail with Binary Attachment Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail

I am attempting to use sp_send_dbmail to send out an attachment.
The attachment is stored in a varbinary(MAX) column in a table. Here is my query:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @recipients='mick.walker@somewhere.com',
        @subject = 'Test Attachment',
        @body = 'Test',
        @body_format = 'HTML',
        @profile_name = 'intranetadmin',
        @query = 'Select DocumentData from [myDB].[dbo].[Documents] Where DocumentID = 8',
        @query_result_header = 0,
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_attachment_filename = 'Test.pdf',
        @exclude_query_output = 1,
        @query_no_truncate = 0;
```

The email sends sucessfully with a pdf attachment. However when it comes to opening the attachment, I get an error. I think the size of the file is being truncated, even though I explicitaally state no to in my query.

I have checked the MAX allowed message size in the Database Mail settings and it is currently 104857600 bytes (100mb), the files I am attempting to send, are nowhere near this size - so I am a little puzzled.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  I'm following your example and I am getting two issues.  One, `\n(1 rows affected)` is being appended to the file.  Fix that with `SET NOCOUNT ON` before your actual query.  (Although this still leaves a `\n` at the end.)  Two, the data is in text format, not binary.  My varbinary(max) column has this data in it:  `0x255044462D312E340A3120...`  That is getting written to the attachment file as literal text, not binary.  I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old thread but I have just come across the same issue.  The problem is SQL reported an error and has stored the error message in the attachment.

Change the name of the attachment to have a `.txt` extension and send the email.  Open the `.txt` file and view the error.  It is probably something to so with a security configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `@query_no_truncate` parameter to 1. When large variable length data types are used in the query and this option is 0 or not specified data gets cut to 256 characters. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx